# Font size of linguistic examples (langsci-gb4e)

Tags: fontsize, linguistics, gb4e

I need to format my thesis in linguistics as required by the publisher. The font has to be Times New Roman 10,2°, spacing 11,9°. While this works for the main text, I cannot change the font size of the examples using `langsci-gb4e` package **strong text**.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}

% language packages
\usepackage[T2A,T1,T3]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{textgreek}

%some more packages

% layout
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\setlength\parindent{6mm}

%some more formatting of bibliography, captions, etc.

% examples
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\renewcommand{\exfont}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont\itshape} 
\renewcommand{\glossfont}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\transfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\exnrfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{ex:specificlabel}
\gll es hungrigs ross\\
a.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} hungry.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} horse \\
\trans `a hungry horse'
\end{exe}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

It does not matter whether I use

```
\renewcommand{\exfont}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont\itshape}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\exfont}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont\itshape}
```

I have also tried using `\eachwordone` instead of `\exfont` as shown here. This works for the first line (example) and the second (glossing), but not the third one (translation) or the number.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}

% language packages
\usepackage[T2A,T1,T3]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{textgreek}

% some more packages

% layout
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\setlength\parindent{6mm}

% some more formatting of bibliography, captions, etc.

% examples
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont\itshape} 
\renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\normalfont\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\exnrfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{ex:specificlabel}
\gll es hungrigs ross\\
a.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} hungry.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} horse \\
\trans `a hungry horse'
\end{exe}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I have also tried not using the `exe` enviroment as suggested in the manual of the `langsci-gb4e` package which also does not help.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}

% language packages
\usepackage[T2A,T1,T3]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[]{textgreek}

% some more packages

% layout
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\AtBeginDocument{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\setlength\parindent{6mm}

% some more formatting of bibliography, captions, etc.

% examples
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont\itshape} 
\renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\eachwordthree}{\normalfont\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\exnrfont}{\normalfont\fontsize{10.2}{11.9}\selectfont}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\ea
\label{ex:specificlabel}
\gll es hungrigs ross\\
a.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} hungry.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} horse \\
\glt `a hungry horse'
\z

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? Every help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're loading `fontenc` with old encodings. You should not do this, because you are using `fontspec` and are compiling with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.  But you need to set up your fonts properly for Russian. You should also not be loading the `textgreek` package, but instead set up Greek properly with `babel`. See the `babel` documentation for how to do that.

A global font change like the one you've added using `\AtBeginDocument` is also not a good idea. Since you're using the KOMA class `scrbook`, your `fontsize=10.2pt` should be all you need.

Then you don't need to do any redefinitions of the `gb4e` macros other than making `\eachwordone` to be `\itshape`.

Then your file compiles, but the Times New Roman font doesn't have small caps (at least the one I have doesn't) so your glossing abbreviations end up being substituted.  This means you need a font that has proper small caps.

```
\documentclass[twoside, 10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}

% language packages

\usepackage[russian,ngerman]{babel}

% some more packages

% layout
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\setlength\parindent{6mm}

% some more formatting of bibliography, captions, etc.

% examples
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{ex:specificlabel}
\gll es hungrigs ross\\
a.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} hungry.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} horse \\
\trans `a hungry horse'
\end{exe}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and your explanations. I have tried to replicate your code. However, while your MWE works, I cannot compile my file when deleting the fontenc-package. I am currently trying to figure out what is causing this problem, but right now I have no clue. If you happen to have any idea -- without having to go through my very long preamble -- I would be very happy. Else I will continue to look for the error.

Comment: @ahasse The problem is likely related to your use of `textgreek`, and possibly anything that you are using related to Russian. As I mentioned, you need to set up both Greek and Russian properly using `babel` and then remove any code that depended on e.g. `textgreek`.

Comment: @ahasse Remember also, to look at the log file and pay attention to the *first* error reported (subsequent errors may not be useful.) Then fix that error and try again. Are you getting undefined control sequence errors or something else?

Comment: Thank you so much @Alain-Munn. I have compiled my preamble bit by bit. I no longer get any erreros and everything is printed in the right font and font size. However, I encountered a related problem. I think that I need `fontenc` nevertheless, but it seems to be interfering with `tipa`. I have posted it as a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655044/fontenc-and-tipa).

Comment: @ahasse The simplest solution for legacy TIPA in a LuaTeX or XeTeX document is here: [Using TIPA with fontspec](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/64830)