# Fontenc and tipa

Tags: font-encodings, linguistics, gb4e, tipa

I am layouting my PhD theses in linguistics and I am struggling with the layout of the linguistic examples. Thanks to StackExchange, I could solve the problem of font size (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/654529/font-size-of-linguistic-examples-langsci-gb4e/654559#654559)). Now, however, I am struggling with using `tipa` and `fontenc`. To me it seems that I need the `fontenc` package because of `tipa` (as suggested in the [tipa documentation](http://www.l.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Efkr/tipa/tipaman.pdf) on page 11). If I do not load `fontenc`, I cannot compile the IPA symbols (instead I am getting the message *! Undefined control sequence*). And if I load `fontenc`, it prints some letters of the remaining text in Greek letters.

Here is a WME and any help is very much appreciated:

```
\documentclass[twoside, fontsize=10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}

%======================================
% === Papierformat ===
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

% === Schriftart ===
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% === Einzüge ===
\setlength\parindent{6mm}

%======================================
% === language packages ===
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%======================================
% === testing ===
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%======================================
% === Querverweise ===
\usepackage{hyperref} % muss vor leipzig geladen werden
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, linkcolor=black,unicode=true,
 citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdfauthor=Hasse, pdfkeywords=}
\urlstyle{same}

%======================================
% === Glossar ===
\usepackage[nomain,style=long,nonumberlist,toc,xindy,nopostdot,sort=def,acronym]{glossaries}% package for creating a glossary and package for leipzig glosses (nomain, weil es in einem separaten file ist)
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} %dann wird glossar in zwei spalten gedruckt

% # \input{glossary.tex}

\usepackage[block]{leipzig}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\leipzigname}{Glossierung}%die Leipzigliste umbenennen

%%customised glossings
\renewleipzig{abl}{abl}{Ablativ}
\renewleipzig{acc}{acc}{Akkusativ}
% some more customised glossings

%======================================
% === linguistic examples ===
%
\usepackage{microtype,booktabs}
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e} %https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/xetex/latex/langsci/documentation/langsci-gb4.pdf

\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape} %italics in first line

%======================================
% === linguistic specific packages ===
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[T2A,T1,T3]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[noenc]{tipa} % overview IPA signs http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/events/lcc/tutorials/tipachart/tipachart.pdf [16.6.2016]

% === new tipa symbols ===
\newcommand\uhalb{\ipabar{u}{.7ex}{.5}{}{.5}}
\newcommand\aganz{\ipabar{a}{.5ex}{0.8}{}{}}

%======================================
%======================================
%======================================
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{5}

\blindtext

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{ex:specificlabel}
\gll es hungrigs ross\\
a.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} hungry.\textsc{nom/acc.neutr} horse \\
\trans `a hungry horse'
\end{exe}

\blindtext

\textsl{\textipa{5}}

\textipa{mid5r5N} gälld

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to try the `tipauni` package as a replacement for `tipa`. I'm not sure whether it covers the full feature set of `tipa`, but at least your example document works with it (you might want to take a close look at its documentation; also please note that it loads `fontspec` and by default the font CharisSIL, you can change the font of your document using its `documentfont` option, or if you want to set up your fonts outside of `tipauni` use the `preservefont` option).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried to use tipauni instead of tipa. It works with most of my document. As soon as I am trying to compile a figure enviroment, however, the PDF cannot be compiled.  Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this problem?

Comment: @ahasse Can you post a minimal working example which demonstrates that a figure doesn't work with `tipauni`?

Comment: Also it would be great if you could tell us what error you get when you use figure with `tipauni`.

Comment: I have just made a MWE and run it... and it works. However, only with a new figure. Weirdly, it no longer works with my old figures which used to be in my theses. So there must be a problem with these files rather than with the code.