# Diacritics not printed correctly with TIPAUNI

Tags: linguistics, tipa, diacritical-mark

I have asked a question on another problem (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655044/fontenc-and-tipa)) and someone suggested using `tipauni` instead of `tipa`. My initial problem (font of IPA symbols) has been solved thanks to this suggestion. However, a number of diacritics are now printed incorrectly (e.g. under instead of above the letter, as with the macron above  or the caron above  in the example below). And two more symbols I have defined myself (one of them is `\uhalb` in the MWE) are no longer printed.
Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this problem?

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[twoside, fontsize=10.2pt, listof=nochaptergap]{scrbook}

%======================================
% === Papierformat ===
\usepackage[paperwidth=17cm, paperheight=24cm, %seitengrösse
outer=2.7cm, inner=2.4cm, top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm, %seitenränder
headsep=0.62cm]{geometry} %abstand von kopfzeile zu text
\setlength{\textheight}{19cm} \setlength{\textwidth}{11.9cm} %satzspiegel definieren

% === Schriftart ===
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

% === Einzüge ===
\setlength\parindent{6mm}

%======================================
% === language packages ===
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%======================================
% === testing ===
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%======================================
% === Querverweise ===
\usepackage{hyperref} % muss vor leipzig geladen werden
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, linkcolor=black,unicode=true,
 citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdfauthor=Hasse, pdfkeywords=}
\urlstyle{same}

%======================================
% === Glossar ===
\usepackage[nomain,style=long,nonumberlist,toc,xindy,nopostdot,sort=def,acronym]{glossaries}% package for creating a glossary and package for leipzig glosses (nomain, weil es in einem separaten file ist)
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} %dann wird glossar in zwei spalten gedruckt

% # \input{glossary.tex}

\usepackage[block]{leipzig}

\makeglossaries

\renewcommand{\leipzigname}{Glossierung}%die Leipzigliste umbenennen

%%customised glossings
\renewleipzig{abl}{abl}{Ablativ}
\renewleipzig{acc}{acc}{Akkusativ}
% some more customised glossings

%======================================
% === linguistic examples ===
%
\usepackage{microtype,booktabs}
\usepackage{langsci-gb4e} %https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/xetex/latex/langsci/documentation/langsci-gb4.pdf

\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape} %italics in first line

%======================================
% === linguistic specific packages ===
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[T2A,T1,T3]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[documentfont=Times New Roman]{tipauni}

% === new tipa symbols ===
\newcommand\uhalb{\ipabar{u}{.7ex}{.5}{}{.5}}
\newcommand\aganz{\ipabar{a}{.5ex}{0.8}{}{}}

%======================================
%======================================
%======================================
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{5}

\blindtext

\textipa{an @ \v{s}tei, \i n @ m\={u}r}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: you shouldn't load fontenc with the unicode engines, that can only harm. Apart from this it looks like a bug, so report it.

Comment: Your question reports two problems. I have fixed one of them in v0.6.1 of the package. Should be visible on CTAN and in the distributions very soon.

Comment: The `tipauni` package focuses on Unicode. Your `\uhalb` and `\aganz` use non-Unicode methods for getting the desired shapes. I am afraid that I can't support them with `tipauni`. I recommend defining the aforementioned macros to produce Unicode characters instead, e.g., we have 'ʉ'.

Comment: The problem with those two macros is the command `\ipabar`. It's a TIPA command and I can't support it. Unfortunately I can't tell you the non-Unicode ways of drawing such bars on letters, but I am pretty sure that it must be very easy with some tricks in LaTeX. Please ask another question, like say, "how to produce a bar over a letter in text mode without TIPA?".

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to strike through a character, you don't really need all the complications of `\ipabar`.

In Unicode there is already U+0289 LATIN SMALL LETTER U BAR, so you might want to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[documentfont=Times New Roman]{tipauni}

% === new tipa symbols ===
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myipabar}[2]{% #1 = letter, #2 = height
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \sbox\z@{\string#1}%
    \vrule width \wd\z@
           height \dimexpr#2\ht\z@+0.05ex\relax
           depth -\dimexpr#2\ht\z@-0.05ex\relax
  }#1%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareRobustCommand\uhalb{\myipabar{u}{.7}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\aganz{\myipabar{a}{.5}}

\begin{document}

\textipa{an @ \v{s}tei, \i n @ m\={u}r}

\textipa{\uhalb \aganz}

\textipa{ʉ}

\end{document}
```

It would be slightly more complicated if you need to strike out an italic character.

[image]